# x-terminal-emulator not getting path

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, path

I have a script that uses `x-terminal-emulator` to launch a different script in a new terminal window.

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and a colleague of mine is using ubuntu 12.10 and this is not working for him, but it is working for me.

When the second script is launched it fails because the second terminal can not find `adb` which is on both our `paths`.

We both have the correct `path` in our `bashrc` files.

What could be causing this issue?

I am calling the second script like the following:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e bash secondScript.sh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the issue.

My colleague was using `xfce` and apparently it will not resolve the `path` correctly from `~/.bashrc`.

We had to add the path to `/etc/bash.basrc` to fix this issue.